# Why does alt+u on a physical keyboard produce braille symbols?

Tags: external-keyboard

If I press alt+u on my bluetooth keyboard Logitech k480 with a text field active, a ⠉ (braille pattern dots-14) is produced. I don't want that. In fact I want programs like JuiceSSH treat it like any other key combination - I want to send alt+u combinations via ssh.

Why does it happen and how do I stop it?